# Infinitesimal Generators and Expectation of First Hitting Time as Solution of Differential Equation

Tags: option-pricing, local-volatility, differential-equations, expected-value, stopping-time

I've been learning about Linear Diffusions and how their infinitesimal generators can be used to relate expectations and deterministic differential equations.

Let $X$ be an one-dimensional diffusion with the following dynamics:

$dX_t = \mu(X_t)dt + \sigma(X_t)dW_t$

Its infinitesimal generator $\mathcal{G}$ takes the form of the following second-order differential operator:

$\mathcal{G}f(x) = \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2(x)\frac{d^2f}{dx^2}(x) + \mu(x)\frac{df}{dx}$

I've seen, for example, that when one defines: $u(x) = Pr( \tau_a < \tau_b | X_0 = x)$, with $a<b$ and $\tau_a$ and $\tau_b$ being their respective hitting times. With some regularity hypothesis under $u$ and by proceeding analogously to a "first step analysis" for discrete Markov Chains, one can show that $u$ is a solution of: $\mathcal{G}u(x) = 0$, with $u(a) = 1$ and $u(b) = 0$ as boundary conditions.

I know this approach is much more general than this simple example and can be used also in the opposite direction. I think it is actually what is done for the Dirichlet's Problem and the Feynman-Kac Formula.

In the article [http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~linetsky/cev.pdf](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/%7Elinetsky/cev.pdf), the authors claim that:

For such a $S$ having the following local volatility dynamics:

$dS_t = \mu S_tdt + \sigma(S_t)S_tdW_t$

The following is true:

$\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau_a}\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_a < \infty\}} | S_0 = x] = \frac{\phi_r(x)}{\phi_r(a)}$, for $ x \geq a$

and

$\mathbb{E}[e^{-r\tau_b}\mathbb{1}_{\{\tau_b < \tau_0 \}} | S_0 = x] = \frac{\psi_r(x)}{\psi_r(b)}$, for $ x \leq b$

where: $\phi_r$ and $\psi_r$ are solutions of:
$\mathcal{G}v = rv$.

$\psi_r$ is required to be an increasing function and $\phi_r$ is required to be a decreasing function such that: $\psi(0+) = (0)$, if $0$ is a regular boundary point (we force 0 to be a killing boundary).

I have no idea how those expectations can be expressed in terms of the solutions of this "eigenvector equation". Could someone please explain to me why? Please, I ask you to be as didactic as possible, once I'm kinda new to the subject.